# Custom alertDialog in the listView

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I can not make a custom Alertdialog in the listview.
The code below works correctly in the MainActivity, but in the customAdapter the "getLayoutInflater ()" is in red:

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder cBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_profil, null);



                        cBuilder.setView(mView);
                        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = cBuilder.create();
                        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change `getLayoutInflater` to `LayoutInflater.from(context)` instead